# Users set as inactive by useradd

Tags: linux

I have to set an inactivity period for users on Debian systems with useradd -f, but I am not sure if this will cause them to lose their home directories if they really become inactive. The man page for useradd says the account will be "permanently disabled". Does that mean it can be activated by root using passwd, or will it be permanently unrecoverable?

Comment: Why not test it. You'll only have to wait a day.